# Determining if two pairs of numbers are interleaved

Tags: javascript

Given `a1 < a2` and `b1 < b2`, I want to return true if and only if `(a1 < b1 < a2 < b2) || (b1 < a1 < b2 < a2)`

Is there a more elegant way to write this than the obvious?

They are calculated from:

```
a1, a2 = c1 +/- d1
b1, b2 = c2 +/- d2
```

with `d1` and `d2` both positive.
A solution in terms of `(c1,c2,d1,d2)` is also fine.

Comment: Looks like you need `abs(c1 - c2) < d1 + d2`

Comment: @ChrisG ```(c1,c2,d1,d2) = (3,4,1,3)``` returns true, but it should return false ```a1,a2 = 3 +/- 1, b1,b2 = 4 +/- 3 -> (b1,a1,a2,b2) = (1,2,4,7)``` I only want to return true if they are interleaved.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "the obvious"?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa "the obvious" is ```(a1 < b1 && b1 < a2 && a2 < b1) || (b1 < a1 && a1 < b2 && b2 < a2)```  I want to return true for sortings of ABAB and BABA and false on AABB, BBAA, ABBA, BAAB, and was looking to take advantage of the symmetry.

Comment: I see, in that case you need `const cd = abs(c1 - c2); if (cd < d1 + d2 && cd > abs(d1 - d2))`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would just create a function and get it's output. This way it will be easier to read and shorter to write.

for example `isInterleaved(a1,a2,b1,b2){... return result}`

Sometimes the most basic ways perform better than the fancy ones, that's why I prefer using this approach.